# Can I re-route POST request traffic in my web config when the url has changed using rewrite?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I am in the process of updating my API calls from www CNAME to api CNAME.  The website and API calls are hosted on an ASP.Net application hosted on Azure web apps.

I am wanting to put a new website onto the www CNAME which is hosted in S3.  So any old api calls, such as `https://www.myexampleorg.com/api/mypostrequest` will no longer be valid.

The issue I have is that I have a mobile application which uses these www calls, I pushed out an update a month ago to change these, but for anyone that doesn't have auto updates on this may not be on their device.  I can also see hundreds of people a day still updating so it's obvious that not everyone has updated that can.

I was hoping to do something like this in my web config... would this work and respond with the correct values as if it were coming from the correct cname?

So `https://www.myexampleorg.com/api/mypostrequest` would return as if it had hit `https://api.myexampleorg.com/api/mypostrequest`?

Or is there any other way around this?

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect old API calls" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.myexampleorg.com/api$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://api.myexampleorg.com/api{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```